# How can I get the image that stored in Firebase Database with the help of Picasso

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

I'am trying to code an application that you can post some photos and texts. I'm okey with getting texts from firebase database however ı cannot access the images that is stored in Storage part of the Firebase (I also added them into database). Images couldn't be loaded and when I checked the logcat, Picasso says that

```
Unrecognized type of request: Request{com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@78d7d49}
```

So i cannot give the download url of the image because images are stored in database as a string like com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@78d7d49

How can I access them ?

```
 public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public BlogViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            TextView post_text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_text);
            post_text.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image) {
            final ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
           // Glide.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);

            Picasso.get().setLoggingEnabled(true);
            Picasso.get().load(image).into(post_image);

//            StorageReference load = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Images").child(image);
//            load.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
//                @Override
//                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
//                    Picasso.get().load(uri.toString()).into(post_image);
//                }
//            });



        }
    }
```

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Images> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Images>()
                .setQuery(mData, Images.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Images, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Images, BlogViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {



            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BlogViewHolder blogViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Images blog) {
                blogViewHolder.setTitle(blog.getTitle());
                blogViewHolder.setDesc(blog.getDesc());
                blogViewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), blog.getImage());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_row, parent, false);
                return new BlogViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        mMainList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
```

```
public class Images {

    private String desc;
    private String image;
    private String title;

    public Images(String desc, String image, String title) {
        this.desc = desc;
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Images() {

    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to get the URL to the image from Firebase Storage and use that as the URL in picasso

Comment: What does the String image field store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your image is url format like this "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/burnab-812eb.appspot.com/o/users%2Fprofile_images%2Fzyp599FGT5NJvTSC0YbKJJRWjqX2.jpg?alt=media&token=8b7a1399-9217-40dd-8a05-49f9b7b7420f"

This way Picasso will able to fetch the image from database.

If you don't have a download url from storage. Then you can achieve this below

```
final StorageReference childRef = storageReference.child("posts/" + user_id + "/" + ts + ".jpg");

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            compressedImageFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 18, baos);
            byte[] thumbData = baos.toByteArray();


            final UploadTask thumb_uploadTask = thumb_childRef.putBytes(thumbData);

            thumb_uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Task<Uri> thumb_uriTask = thumb_uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    throw task.getException();
                                }
                                return thumb_childRef.getDownloadUrl();
                            }
                        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                  Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

                                                            final String mUri = downloadUri.toString();
                                                            final HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
                                                            dataMap.put("profile_image", profile_image);

                                                            if (bundle != null) {
                                                                group_id = bundle.getString("group_id");
                                                                dataMap.put("group_id", group_id);
                                                                mDatabase.child("group").child(group_id).child("posts").push().setValue(dataMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                            pd.dismiss();
                                                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Post added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                            onBackPressed();
                                                                        } 
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            });
```